# Freeing an already allocated memory by C.free(unsafe.Pointer) is crashing my program

Tags: go, dll, cgo

I'm calling C APIs defined in another C library (main.dll) from my go code using cgo. The C API returns a ApiResponse pointer which populates error code and message. The memory for ApiResponsePtr is allocated by C API. After using this, when I call C.free to free the allocated memory, it crashes.

> Crash log says : exit status 0xc0000374

Below is the working code, which can be used as it is.
Note I've used MSVC to create a main.dll from the main.c and main.h file. The same main.dll is linked in my go code.

**main.go**

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
#cgo CFLAGS: -I./
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L./ -lmain
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {

    var apiResponse *C.ApiResponse
    var instanceID *C.char

    property := C.CString(".\\properties")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(property))

    apiResponse = C.create_instance(property, &instanceID)

    id := C.GoString(instanceID)

    // I'm able to access data from apiResponse
    stat := int32(apiResponse.status)
    fmt.Println("status : ", stat)
    fmt.Println("response : ", C.GoString(apiResponse.response))
    fmt.Println("instanceID : ", id)

    fmt.Println("Before call to free apiResponse")
    // When I call free of the allocated memory, its crashing
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(apiResponse))
    fmt.Println("After call to free apiResponse")

    os.Exit(0)
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"

void GetInstaceID(char ** instanceID)
{
    char * temp = NULL;
    
    if(instanceID) {
        
        temp = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LEN_ID);
        if(temp){
            memset(temp, 0, MAX_LEN_ID);
            strncpy(temp, "ABC-XYX-1234", MAX_LEN_ID-1);
        }
        
        *instanceID = temp;
    }
}

ApiResponsePtr create_instance(char * property, char ** instanceID)
{

    ApiResponsePtr ptr = NULL;
    ptr = (ApiResponse *) calloc(1, sizeof(ApiResponse));

    // Internally it allocates memory for instanceID and fill ID
    GetInstaceID(instanceID);

    // Do other stuff

    // Fill ptr
    ptr->status = 0;

    
    ptr->response = (char *)malloc(MAX_STATUS_LEN * sizeof(char));
    if(ptr->response) {
        strncpy(ptr->response, "Success", MAX_STATUS_LEN-1); //hardcoding response as Success, actual would decide based on status
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

**main.h**

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_
#define MAIN_H_

#define MAX_LEN_ID      30
#define MAX_STATUS_LEN  64
//#define INSTANCE_ID "ABC-XYX-1234" // hard coding here, actual code would generate it

typedef struct api_response_t
{
    int     status;         /*!< \details API status code */
    char    * response;     /*!< \details API response message  */
} ApiResponse, *ApiResponsePtr;

ApiResponsePtr create_instance(char * property, char ** instanceID);

#endif
```

Comment: I suspect your MSVC DLL might be using a different memory allocator. The calloc/free calls look fine in the code. It works fine for me if I remove "LDFLAGS" and allow Go to build and link main.c by itself. That makes me suspect Go's use of "C.free" refers to a different allocator that the MSVC "calloc" call.

Perhaps try moving the "free" call into your DLL so it will use the same allocator.